# Modify /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart before boot

Tags: bash, boot, grep, startup, lxde

I have some parameters that I would like to change in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`, before it is run. I get the parameters from a grep command. I would like to feed them to the `autostart` file but am not sure how.

Currently, what I have is `grep "stuff" /file/one` which outputs 1234.

I want to put 1234 in the `autostart` file like

```
....
@program 1234
....
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, there is probably a million ways to do this and the way I read your question your are going about your problem the wrong way, but first things first.

After entering your username and password correctly all the scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` are sourced (not run, that's a very important difference!) in alphabetical order. So if you want some logic to happen after login, but before your desktop environment starts, that's the place to put your scripts.

In such a script you could put

```
for item in $(grep "stuff" /file/one)
do
  echo "@program ${item}" >> /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
done
```

That will add the lines you want to file you want to add them to. It's the '>>' that makes the shell append the lines to the end of the file, rather than replacing the file. That's the answer to your question.

Now here's the problem: with such a script the result of your `grep` will be added to the autostart file every time you log in to your machine. So the first time that program will be run once. The next time you log in twice and three times on your next login. The list of your autostart programs will keep growing as long as your grep yields results to add to the autostart file. That's why I initially said you are going about your problem the wrong way.

Further, there is not just the global `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`. You can have a file `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` for each individual user. Even if you are the only user working on your machine you should rather edit the file in your home directory (`~` expands to your home directory) than the global one.

And as final advice if you want to run programs, just add an entry to your `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` for a shell script that does a for loop as stated above, but instead of adding lines to some file you actually run the commands. When you run commands with an `&` at the end of the line those programs will be run in the background and the script will not block.